# Newtonsoft.Json Usage in long trees

Tags: c#, json, json.net, console-application, json-deserialization

I'm trying so scrape some info from a JSON response but it fails; I think it may have to do with the way I'm making use of a library I'm new to.

Below is the JSON instance that I'm trying to get data from;

```
{
   "profileChanges":[
      {
         "changeType":"fullProfileUpdate",
         "profile":{
            "stats":{
               "attributes":{
                  "allowed_to_receive_gifts":true,
                  "allowed_to_send_gifts":true,
                  "ban_history":{},
                  //This is what I'm trying to scrape the EpicPCKorea string
                  "current_mtx_platform":"EpicPCKorea",
                  "daily_purchases":{},
                  "gift_history":{},
                  "import_friends_claimed":{},
                  "in_app_purchases":{
                     "fulfillmentCounts":{
                        "2E5AC9924F2247325BBB22AC9AF9965B":1
                     },
                     "receipts":[
                        "EPIC:543a35e70dde4e0aaf56a9e0b76c8f67"
                     ]
                  },
                  "inventory_limit_bonus":0,
                  "mfa_enabled":false,
                  "monthly_purchases":{},
                  "mtx_affiliate":"",
                  "mtx_purchase_history":{},
                  "weekly_purchases":{}
               }
            },
            "updated":"2018-12-06T14:37:27.797Z",
         }
      }
   ],
   "profileChangesBaseRevision":31,
   "serverTime":"2018-12-30T18:44:35.451Z"
}
```

Here, my code in C#;

```
//str4 is the json response that I just posted up.
dynamic json    = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str4); 
string platform = json.profileChanges.profile.stats.attributes.current_mtx_platform;
```

But it doesn't work at all.

I debugged it and found out this Exception:

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'profile'
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1. You didn't show full json data(current has invalid schema). 2. `profileChanges` is a collection, so it possibly is: `json.profileChanges[0].profile`. 3. _But it doesn't work at all_ - is not a specific problem we can help with, please provide more information, did you get an error/exception? what is the exception message or possible StackTrace?

Comment: `profileChanges` is an array so you have to access it as an array, so you can't do `json.profileChanges.profile`, `json.profileChanges` does not contain a property called `profile` because it's an array, hence .`....JArray' does not contain a definition for 'profile'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments under your question, `profileChanges` is an array so you need to specify which item in the array to access.

Are you sure the the below does not work?  It works for me...

```
string platform = json.profileChanges[0].profile.stats.attributes.current_mtx_platform;
```